# Use RestSharp Post Object as JSON and read it from the other side of the call

Tags: c#, json, post, restsharp

I have a C# REST Web API and I have some code like this that makes a request to an endpoint. Some of the data that I want to pass along is an object of my own type and since it is a complex object, I would like to pass it using POST.

```
RestClient client = new RestClient(Constants.Endpoints.serviceEndPoint)
{
    Timeout = 1000
};

string requestResource = Constants.Endpoints.apiEndPoint;
RestRequest request = new RestRequest(requestResource, Method.POST);
request.AddParameter("Authorization", $"Bearer {accessToken}", ParameterType.HttpHeader);
request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
request.AddParameter("id", id, ParameterType.UrlSegment);
request.AddParameter("text/json", objectIWantToSerialize, ParameterType.RequestBody);

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

On the other side, I am trying to read the object itself with some code like this

```
var provider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();

await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

    foreach (var content in provider.Contents)
    { 
       // what should I do here to read the content as a JSON 
       // and then transform it as the object it used to be before the call?
    }
```

I tried to do **await content.ReadAsJsonAsync< MyType>();** but also tried **await content.ReadAsStringAsync();** and none of these worked. Am I doing something wrong at the time I execute in the client? Or is it something that I am doing on the other side while reading the content?

Comment: Have you tried using a debugging proxy such as [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to see what is actually being sent to the server?

Comment: I actually used Fiddler and I noticed that the value being sent is not the JSON form of the object at all. Does it mean that the request.AddParameter is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this line:
`request.AddParameter("text/json", objectIWantToSerialize, ParameterType.RequestBody);`

You should use the `.AddBody(object)` method.
So you're code would look like this:

```
RestRequest request = new RestRequest(requestResource, Method.POST);
//add other headers as needed
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
request.AddBody(objectIWantToSerialize);

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

On the server, if you're using MVC/WebAPI, you can just put the C# type as the input and ASP.NET will deserialize it for you. If not, can you provide more context about how you're receiving the request?